# How do I extract device info and mountpoints from fstab using Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I really need help witch a specific issue.

I need to extract info from my fstab, but there's a lot of information in there and I only want the information about the devices and their mount points.
The closest I got to finding an answer was:
http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/vinum/perl.html

But since I'm new to Perl I have a hard time tweaking the code so it helps me with my problem

This is my fstab, but I only want the 3 "dev" lines including mountpoints, any smart way to do this?

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-ST925041_0AS_FF9250410A0000000000005FF87FF7-part2 /                    
ext3       noatime,nodiratime,acl,user_xattr 1 1
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-ST925041_0AS_FF9250410A0000000000005FF87FF7-part3 /var/log             
ext3       noatime,nodiratime,acl,user_xattr 1 2
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-ST925041_0AS_FF9250410A0000000000005FF87FF7-part1 swap                 swap       
defaults              0 0
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0 0
sysfs                /sys                 sysfs      noauto                0 0
debugfs              /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs    noauto                0 0
usbfs                /proc/bus/usb        usbfs      noauto                0 0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0 0
```

Help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `"This is my fstab. There are many like it, but this one is mine."` Is that the output from your perl script, and you only want the first three lines? Or what are you asking?

Comment: By the way, the script in your link is 11 years old.

Comment: Yes this is the output I get, and I want to filter it so I only get the device names, for example:
/dev/disk/*/*/*/*part2 (mountpoint)

For all 3 devices

Comment: Some advice: If you ask a question "How can I edit this 500 line script to do what I want?", you'll get no answers. If you ask "How can I extract these lines from this output?" you'll have an answer within minutes.

Comment: I've tried asking like that but I've only gotten information on how to get the information from the file, and I know how to do that
And as stated in the question, I can't take "general" answers, becuase I can't tweak codes yet so they help me

Comment: I am confused. Is it not your goal to get the information from the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is your output, and you just want to grab the lines that start with `/dev`, you can simply pipe it to grep, without altering your perl script.

```
perlscript.pl | grep "^/dev"
```

Not sure if that works without the `-e` flag, its been a while and I can't test it right now. If all else fails, use perl:

```
perlscript.pl | perl -nwe 'print if m#^/dev#'
```

Comment: Strange because I've tried this before, but back then I used another command to open the file and print it

Now when I use backticks this simple coding helped
Thanks! for the help =) Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be just fine, then :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (my $fstab, "<", "/etc/fstab") or die "Cannot open /etc/fstab.";

while(<$fstab>)
{
    my @list = split;
    next if($list[0] !~ m,^/dev,);
    print "Device : $list[0]\nMountpoint : $list[1]\n";
}

close($fstab);
exit 0;
```

Keep in mind that this will not work if your fstab has UUID= entries or any kind of file systems that aren't devices listed in /dev.

Comment: You need to use the `m` in `m///` if you're going to use another delimiter. E.g.: `m,^/dev,`

Comment: You can do that in a one-liner: `perl -ane 'printf("Device: %s\nMountpoint: %s\n", @F[0,1]) if $F[0] =~ m#^/dev#;' /etc/fstab`

Comment: You should post that as an answer. My Perl skills are no match for your, apparently.

Comment: On the other hand, your *nix mojo seems to be stronger than mine. No, the answer is yours. I only told you how to spruce it up.